# Where does this akka-http test import Marshaller?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am looking at this akka-http docs example (which links to akka-http test code):

[Marshalling](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/marshalling.html)

This is actually a test from github code [MarshalSpec.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/docs/src/test/scala/docs/http/scaladsl/MarshalSpec.scala). My question is, where is the implicit Marshaller imported here? I am looking at imports, and I couldn't find it? I tried using IntelliJ to show me implicit imports, but I still couldn't figure this out. Where is the import statement that gets the implicit declaration for a Marshaller that is passed to:

```
  val entityFuture = Marshal(string).to[MessageEntity]
```

at line 21?
It calls

```
def to[B](implicit m: Marshaller[A, B], ec: ExecutionContext): Future[B] =
```

in Marshal.scala and passes an implicit m: Marshaller, which I can't pinpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Marshaller` extends `PredefinedToEntityMarshallers` , which provides marshalling from String.

But, why does Marshaller comes with its own implicits ? It's because scala search for implicits in the implicit scope of type arguments : [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

So, Marshaller comes with its own Marshallers ready to use :)

Comment: Aaah, the companion object of the type!!! I forgot this and was trying to find it in the current scope. `object Marshaller
  extends GenericMarshallers
  with PredefinedToEntityMarshallers
  with PredefinedToResponseMarshallers
  with PredefinedToRequestMarshallers { ....
`